# Lost element id after flash message rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application.html.erb I have:

```
    <body<% if iscontact? %> id="contact"<% end %>>'
```

In the same file I have:

```
    <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    </div>'
```

After a validation error occurs I lose the style attached to the id that I added to the body (the "contact" id above). I lose the id and thus I lose the styling.

The example can be seen on http://dev.mym5realty.com/contact. Simply click the send button and you will see the id is lost. PLEASE do not send a real message. PLEASE.

Is there any way to prevent losing the id after a flash message?

I also lose the close button image after a validation error ... very similar if iscontact? page then show the button image.

So it seems that my application_helper is not executing OR somewhere in the flash process it is not on '/contact' page.

```
def iscontact?
if current_page?('/contact')
  return true
end

return false
end
```

and the controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

def new
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])

if @message.valid?
  NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
  redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
else
  flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
  render :new
end
end
```

Comment: Your flash object should have nothing to do with your application helper methods. Can you post the iscontact? method and the controller actions that generate the GET and POST versions of the contact view?

Comment: can you show `iscontact?` code?

Comment: Sorry guys... I decided to do redirect_to(contact_path, :alert => "Error")   And it worked.   Why didn't the other code work? I am still curious.

Comment: you solved it will mark

Comment: @juanpastas: Don't add pseudo-tags to the title. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation suggests that you explicitly declare the controller and actions in the `current_page?` method. Here is the link: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

You could potentially use something like this:

```
def iscontact?
  if current_page?(:controller => 'contact', :action => 'new')
    return true
  elsif current_page?(:controller => 'contact', :action => 'create')
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Cheers!